# How to check cell contain filter or not in excel sheet through oledb reader?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

How to check cell contain filter or not in excel sheet through oledb excel reader?

want method or code for the same..
[image: check below]

Answer (score 1):

I had some solution with Interop you can check this , it may resolve your problem...

```
public bool IsFilterExistInExcel(string excelpath)
    {
        bool IsFilterExist=false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workBooks = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            workBook = workBooks.Open(excelpath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            IsFilterExist = workSheet.AutoFilterMode;
            return IsFilterExist;

}
```